# [__NSCFString absoluteString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance, attempt to convert url to string

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage

Looking to simply convert the parse image url to a string so I can use SDWebImage for caching, etc.

After researching I found that I can convert from a url to string by calling absoluteString on the NSURL. I've also tried this:

```
NSURL *theUrl = [[obj objectForKey:@"image"] url];


NSString *finalUrl = [theUrl absoluteString];

[cell.carPhoto setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:finalUrl]
                           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

but  I am also crashing on this line with the same error

```
NSString *finalUrl = [theUrl absoluteString];
```

Any ideas? By the way obj is a PFObject

Comment: Clearly this means that `[obj[@"image"] url]` is returning an `NSString`, not an `NSURL`. Looks at where your add the value for the "image" key. You are adding an `NSString`, not an `NSURL`.

Comment: It looks like [[obj objectForKey:@"image"] url] is an NSString and not an NSURL. Can you try [cell.carPhoto setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theUrl]
                           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

Comment: Why do you think you need to convert from URL to string and then immediately back to URL anyways?

Comment: would by any chance `obj` be a PFFile instance? if yes, `url` returns a string, you don't need to call absoluteString, it already is one.

Comment: NSString *theUrl = [[obj objectForKey:@"image"] url]; does not work, its not a string..it tells me imcompatiable pointer type initializing NSString with an expression of type NSURl, it was a typo I meant NSURL there not NSString

Comment: Your edits don't change anything. `[[obj objectForKey:@"image"] url]` is still returning an `NSString`, not an `NSURL`. The fact that your `theUrl` variable is declared as an `NSURL` is irrelevant. The value assigned to the `theUrl` is still actually an `NSString`.

Comment: @James In my answer, I explain why NSString *theUrl = [[obj objectForKey:@"image"] url]; doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

The error message is telling you that you have an instance of `__NSCFString`, and you're calling `absoluteString` on it. `__NSCFString` is a kind of `NSString`, so the situation is simply that you expect (for some reason) that you have an `NSURL`, but you actually have an `NSString` - so you don't need to call `absoluteString`.

It would be good to understand why you think you have an `NSURL` and whether you will ever have one in this piece of code. The inputs should really be consistent, but if not you can check the class and decide how to get the string version.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to convert a `NSString` to an `NSURL` with this line:

```
NSURL *theUrl = [[obj objectForKey:@"image"] url];
```

But that's not how you convert an `NSString` to an `NSURL` and so your `NSString` isn't being changed to an `NSURL` as you'd like. Instead, it seems as if it's remained an `NSString`, thus the error.

There's no need to convert the `NSString` to an `NSURL` if the only purpose of that `NSURL` is to be converted back to an `NSString` on the next line by accessing its `absoluteString` property; but if you *do* in fact need `theURL` to be an `NSURL` for reasons beyond the code you've posted (for example, if you need to access the `NSURL` variable later in your code), try this instead to properly convert your string into an url:

```
NSURL *theUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[obj objectForKey:@"image"]];
```

Comment: Since the OP is trying to call `absoluteString`, it is clear the goal is to end up with an `NSString`. There is no need to create an `NSURL` from the `NSString` just so it can be converted back to an `NSString`.

Comment: @rmaddy Unless, like I said, he "needs theURL to in fact be an NSURL for reasons beyond the code you've posted." Like if he needs to use the variable elsewhere. Other than in that one line.

Comment: @rmaddy I can clarify that further in my answer.